# Is it possible to get the data in text box and checkbox to saved in pdf file

Tags: android

I want to design my own pdf file and to save in sdcard with the data from text box and Checkbox from my android app.The pdf format requires tabular column,images,checkbox.PDF should be like an user agreement form

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information.  Consider looking at android.graphics.pdf or a third party PDF api.

Comment: yes you can do this using itext lib. refer http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-text-pdf

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html

Comment: Thank you @VishalThakkar.I will try and implement the same